# Java: hashCode for AbstractSet vs. AbstractList

Tags: java

For AbstractList, the hash code is computed as follows:

```
 int hashCode = 1;
 Iterator<E> i = list.iterator();
 while (i.hasNext()) {
     E obj = i.next();
     hashCode = 31*hashCode + (obj==null ? 0 : obj.hashCode());
 }
```

while for AbstractSet, it's computed as follows:

```
int h = 0;
Iterator<E> i = iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    E obj = i.next();
    if (obj != null)
        h += obj.hashCode();
}
```

Question: why can't AbstractList's hash code computation be same as that of AbstractSet's? Has this got anything to do with possible element duplication in `List` vs. unique element guarantee in `Set`, or is it about `ordered` vs. `un-ordered` property of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely.  The hash code calculation specified in the `List` interface makes it likely that the `hashCode()` of two lists with the same elements ordered in different ways will be different.  The hash code specified in the `Set` interface guarantees that the hash code of two `Set`s with the same elements in different orders will be the same.

That corresponds naturally with the differing notions of equality for `List` and `Set`.

Comment: you beat me to writing so i won't provide a dup answer. this is right. As you see with set, it is just adding each element's hashcode - ordering makes no difference in summation (commutative property) - as the poster mentioned, two sets with smae elements in different order are considered the same (in math principles). With a list, having the same elements in different order is a unique list. The 31*hashcode is, effectively, a "bit shift" trick to 'randomize' the bits before adding the next element's hash, to provide better uniqueness.

Comment: @speakingcode Indeed, and to esure a better uniqueness the used number must be prime (and odd, which is kind of redundant). 31 is commonly used, and it's ok here. As a side note, I've readed about some cases in which a higher number is better (i.e. `String`, if I'm not mistaken).